# Dynamically set imageview height and width in a listview

Tags: listview, android-imageview

i need to be able to get the device screen width and set that to a imageview height and width. The imageview is in a listview. I currently set the layoutparams for the imageview in the baseadapter class i'm using for the listview. But this slows the scrolling of the listview. When i remove the below code the listview scrolls fine. any help?

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, width);
holder.myimageview.setlayoutParams(rlp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try these scroll view parameters?

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/postlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    >
</ListView>
```

The Android: fastScrollEnabled and the Android: scrollingCache have improved my user experience.

Also have look the following [advice to improve your scroll speed](http://leftshift.io/6-ways-to-make-your-lists-scroll-faster-than-the-wind)